# How did Einstein integrate $\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial x'}+\frac{v}{c^2-v^2}\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial t}=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, linear-transformations, partial-derivative

> In his paper "On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies", Einstein writes the equation
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial \tau}{\partial x'}+\dfrac{v}{c^2-v^2}\dfrac{\partial \tau}{\partial t}=0$$
>
> where
>
> - $\tau=\tau(x',y,z,t)$ is a linear function (i.e. $\tau=Ax'+By+Cz+Dt$)
> - $x'=x-vt$
> - $\dfrac{\partial \tau}{\partial y}=0$ (i.e. $B=0$)
> - $\dfrac{\partial \tau}{\partial z}=0$ (i.e. $C=0$)
> - $c$ is a constant
> - $x,x',y,z,t,v$ are variables
>
> and he derives that
>
> $$\tau=a\left(t-\dfrac{v}{c^2-v^2}x'\right)$$
>
> where $a=a(v)$

Could someone please walk me through step-by-step how he derived this? I am not very familiar with integrals invovling partial derivatives, so I would be appreciative if any answers are quite explicit.

Additionally, if I modified the question to say that $\tau$ was an affine function (i.e. $\tau=Ax'+By+Cz+Dt+E$), would it make any difference to the result (I suspect it wouldn't)?

Comment: It seems like [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/335984/mathematics-on-the-electrodynamics-of-moving-bodies-where-am-i-wrong) could be of help for you.

Comment: The question is strictly about the derivation of the differential equation's solution. Hadn't the OP mentioned physics at all, it would still be a perfectly fine question for this site.

Comment: @NikiDiGiano I guess I overreacted. I retracted my close vote but the question I found on physics stackexchange could be useful nevertheless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the definitions given:
$$\partial_{x'}\tau = A, \quad \partial_t \tau = D$$
Also:
$$\partial_{y}\tau = B = 0, \quad \partial_z \tau = C = 0$$
From the differential equation we get:
$$A + \frac{v}{c^2 - v^2}D = 0 \\
\implies A = - \frac{v}{c^2 - v^2}D$$
Now using the definition given for $\tau$:
$$\tau = - \frac{v}{c^2 - v^2}Dx' + Dt = D\bigg(t - \frac{v}{c^2 - v^2}x'\bigg)$$
So if you define $D=a$ you get the final expression for $\tau$. As you have noticed, requiring $\tau$ to be affine doesn't change the results at all - your $\tau$ would be:
$$ \tau = a\bigg(t - \frac{v}{c^2 - v^2}x'\bigg) + E$$
The reason $a=a(v)$ is because $D$, who is actually $a$ in disguise, does not depend on $x', y, z, t$ but is assumed to depend on $v$. Otherwise, the relation wouldn't be linear. Without further information, $a$ is a function of potentially anything except those four variables.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I am just thinking through your answer at the moment, trying to get my head round it. I am just trying to see how you got from $A=-\frac{v}{c^2-v^2}D$ to $\tau=a\left(t-\frac{v}{c^2-v^2}x'\right)+E$. Could you perhaps extend your answer a little to show every step?

Comment: I have added the missing intermediate step. It's just a matter of plugging the results in the original expression.

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes perfect sense - brilliant answer!

Answer (score 8):

There is really *no* need to assume that $\tau$ is linear or affine to derive the general form of $\tau$. Write the equation as 
$$
\frac{\partial\tau}{\partial x'}+k\frac{\partial\tau}{\partial t} = 0 ,
$$
where $k={v}/({c^2-v^2})$. Change coordinates from $(x',t)$ to $(\xi,u)$ by 
$$
\begin{cases}\xi= x'\\
u=t-k x'
\end{cases}
\qquad
\text{or equivalently,}\qquad
\begin{cases}x'=\xi\\
t=u+k\xi.
\end{cases}
$$
This gives
$$
\frac{\partial\tau}{\partial\xi} = \frac{\partial\tau}{\partial x'} \frac{\partial x'}{\partial\xi}+ \frac{\partial\tau}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial\xi} = \frac{\partial\tau}{\partial x'}+k\frac{\partial\tau}{\partial t} = 0 ,
$$
meaning that in the new coordinates, $\tau$ is a function of only $u$. Hence
$$
\tau=a(u)=a(t-k x'),
$$
for some function $a$. At this point, you can use the assumption that $\tau$ is linear (or affine) to deduce that $a$ is linear (or affine).

Comment: Thank you, this is another interesting approach. I especially like that it finds a general form before invoking the linearity of $\tau$, because it would allow us to proceed in a different way if for some reason we decided that the universe wasn't homogeneous (which forces $\tau$ to be linear/affine). If only I could tick multiple answers!

Comment: Indeed this answer is much more elegant than mine in my opinion. Props!

Answer (score 0):

Making the change of variables

$$
x'=x- vt\\
t'=\alpha t
$$

we have

$$
(v^2+\alpha(c^2-v^2))\frac{\partial\tau}{\partial x'}+v\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial t'}=0
$$

so choosing

$$
\alpha = \frac{v^2}{v^2-c^2}
$$

we get

$$
\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial t'} = 0\Rightarrow \tau(x',t') = f(x') = f(x-v t)
$$